# Elm specify number to me Int

Tags: elm

I am trying to see if length of a given list equals some number. However `==` expects two numbers not Int, so even when I type `(==) 1` type is still `number -> Bool` so finally when I pipe in result of `lenght` I get compilation error:

> -- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------------------------------- REPL
>
> This function cannot handle the argument sent through the `(|>)` pipe:
>
> ```
> 4|   List.length |> ((==) 1)
>                      ^^^^^^
> ```
>
> The argument is:
>
> ```
> List a -> Int
> ```
>
> But `(|>)` is piping it to a function that expects:
>
> ```
> number
> ```
>
> Hint: Only Int and Float values work as numbers.

So how can I specify that my constant is an Int as opposed to number variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `>>` to compose functions.

`isLengthOne = List.length >> ((==) 1)` is a function that checks that the length of a list is 1.

`|>` pipes the output of one statement to the input of the next.

So `aList |> List.length |> ((==) 1)` would check `aList`.

Comment: Ooooh, that `>>` is nice. Following a tag on stack is such a great way to learn more about new languages. Never knew there was an operator for composition.

Comment: AND there is `<<` which just composes the other way (for readability). e.g. `notEmpty = not << List.isEmpty`

Comment: Thank you for that, feels like I'm coding in haskell again.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be overthinking this, checking for equality is as straight forward in Elm as in other languages.

```
myList = [1, 2, 3]
List.length myList == 3 // True
```

If you do want to use the `(==)` function, in case you're doing currying or for other reasons

```
List.length myList |> (==)
```

And then you could either store that as a variable or invoke it right away

```
List.length myList |> (==) 3 // True
```

OR

```
lengthChecker = List.length myList |> (==)
lengthChecker 3 // True
```

But I would say it's better to stick to the simple version of just doing the check with `==`.

Just to expand on why your attempt wasn't compiling, the signature for `(==)` is `(==) : a -> a -> Bool` meaning it's a function that takes one argument, `a`, and returns a function that takes one argument, `a` and returns a `Bool`. So in your case `((==) 1)` is a function that wants a `number`. When you do `List.length |> ((==) 1)` you're trying to call that function that expects a number with the `List.length` function itself.